# How to add my listings to the table of contents?

Tags: listings

I am using the [`thesul`](http://www.loria.fr/~roegel/TeX/TUL.html) class.
I would like to add my listings to the table of contents.

I found a way to do that by using the `\addcontentsline{toc}{spsection}{Listings}` command:

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{spsection}{Listings}
```

But the problem is that the corresponding PDF bookmark that was already added is added a second time because of the use of this command.

So, maybe I need to modify the `thesul.cls` file.

---

Edit 1: Sorry, I forgot the `tulhypref` package, so there are no bookmarks with this `main.tex` file.
Here is the correct `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{thesul}
\usepackage{tulhypref} % for bookmarks
\usepackage{listings} % for \lstlistoflistings
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \lstlistoflistings
    \addcontentsline{toc}{spsection}{Listings}
    \chapter{My first chapter}

    Hello, this is my first chapter.

    \section{My first section}

    Hello, this is my first section.

    \begin{lstlisting}
echo "hello world";
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit 2: Here is the result:
[image]

But I found a workaround.

When I use the `\lstlistoflistings` command, I need to do:

```
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}
\lstlistoflistings
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth}
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{thesul}
\usepackage{tulhypref} % for bookmarks
\usepackage{listings} % for \lstlistoflistings
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1} % add this line (to disable bookmarks)
    \lstlistoflistings
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth} % add this line (to enable bookmarks)
    \addcontentsline{toc}{spsection}{Listings}
    \chapter{My first chapter}

    Hello, this is my first chapter.

    \section{My first section}

    Hello, this is my first section.

    \begin{lstlisting}
echo "hello world";
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: please edit your code to be complete. as it is there is no bookmarks, if `hyperref` package add there is no probleme. However it's better if you type `\cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{spsection}{Listings}
    \lstlistoflistings`

Comment: `spsection` is bookmark level unknown to `hyperref`, but this isn't an issue. There is no 2nd bookmark by `\addcontentsline`

Comment: Indeed, sorry I forgot to add the "hyperref" package. Here, we have no bookmarks at all as I have forgot to use this package. But "hyperref" is not compatible with "thesul". It is recommended to use the "tulhypref" package. That's here that the problem happens! So, I think the problem is in the "tulhypref.sty" file. With "hyperref" no problem (there is no 2nd bookmark). Do you see the problem inside the "tulhypref.sty" file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `listings` built-in mechanism I'd rather define a new floating environment and use that together with `lstlisting` (just like you use a `table` float together with a `tabular` environment):

The following runs smoothly and gives the expected results:

```
\documentclass{thesul}
\usepackage{tulhypref} % for bookmarks
\usepackage{listings} % for \lstlistoflistings

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext = lol ,
  listname = {List Of Listings} ,
  name = Listing
]{listing}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listoflistings

\chapter{My first chapter}
Hello, this is my first chapter.

\section{My first section}
Hello, this is my first section.

\begin{listing}
  \begin{lstlisting}
echo "hello world";
  \end{lstlisting}
  \caption{My listing's caption.}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```